# What is the reward for giving Umbra to Clavicus Vile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I got the sword Umbra from beating Umbra (the Bosmer warrior) in the Ayleid ruin of Vindasel. I like the Sword but I also have the quest from Clavicus Vile to return it to him.

What is the reward for giving him the sword?

Comment: Sorry, Enraged.  We don't do opinions here at Arqade.  We can give you the objective information on the choices available to you, but the choice you make is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Frank We have edited the question so it is no longer an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you give Umbra to Clavicus Vile, he will give you the [Masque of Clavicus Vile](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Masque_of_Clavicus_Vile_(Oblivion)). The Masque is a Daedric Helmet (heavy armour) that looks awesome and fortifies your personality by 20.

If you keep Umbra, then you get Umbra, the soul-trapping daedric sword you've already seen. Umbra is also weightless while you are one the quest, since it is a quest item. If you intend to keep it, it may be worth not turning the quest in at all.

Comment: I'd like to add that lore wise in the end it doesn't matter if the Hero of Kvatch/Champion of Cyrodiil keeps Umbra or not. in the [Infernal City book](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Books:The_Infernal_City) which is set after the Oblivion Crisis Clavicus Vile has gotten Umbra as in the book it escapes from Oblivion to Vvardenfell